# Where'd the Link Go to Upgrade G1 Dev Phone to 1.6

Tags: android

So, this HTC site is supposed to have links to update the g1 dev phones (and I've used it before).

http://www.htc.com/www/support/android/adp.html

Now, it seems like the update links are no longer there - Anyone know what's going on, or where I can get 1.6?

Comment: The links are back as of today!

Comment: For information where to find updates for your phone you should go to superuser.com -- Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a clearer community answer, because I know I've run into this before:

HTC only lets you download from their site if the referrer is developer.htc.com.  So you need to use a script which fakes the referrer:

```
#!/bin/sh 
IDIOTS1="http://developer.htc.com" 
IDIOTS2="http://member.america.htc.com/download/RomCode/ADP" 
wget "--referer=$IDIOTS1" "$IDIOTS2/ota-radio-2_22_19_26I.zip" 
wget "--referer=$IDIOTS1" "$IDIOTS2/signed-dream_devphone_userdebug- 
img-14721.zip" 
wget "--referer=$IDIOTS1" "$IDIOTS2/signed-dream_devphone_userdebug- 
ota-14721.zip"
```

You can replace the links as necessary (all the names still line up, so you can get 1.5, 1.1, etc.)

(Data from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e894abe86a7827ac/3347f8da43171591))

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there were some licensing or legal issues with posting the images on HTC's site which, after over a month, haven't resulted in either a solution or an explanation being posted.

See this android-developers thread for info:
http://groups.google.com/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/browse_thread/thread/a6acc9036ee66c06

Comment: And here are two links with alternative download instructions (YMMV): http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e894abe86a7827ac/3347f8da43171591 http://codethought.com/blog/?p=241